# Are len(string) and len(slice)s O(1) operation in Go?

Tags: go

```golang
var s string
var slice []int

len(s)
len(slice)
```

Is the `len()` call on `string`s and slices, O(1).

From [this](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) golang official blog, I can see that the slices have the length, capacity and pointer to the underlying array. So I understood, that the len() on it may be a O(1) operation. But what about strings? Is the length of strings also internally associated with the data so that len() just looks it up and returns it?

I looked at the source [builtin.go](https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go?s=5926:5946#L148) but couldn't make anything out of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A string [header](https://godoc.org/reflect#StringHeader) contains a pointer to the backing array and a length.

The `len()` function returns the length field from [string](https://godoc.org/reflect#StringHeader) and [slice](https://godoc.org/reflect#SliceHeader) headers. It's an O(1) operation.

Regarding builtin.go. The file says:

> Package builtin provides documentation for Go's predeclared identifiers.
>       The items documented here are not actually in package builtin
>       but their descriptions here allow godoc to present documentation
>       for the language's special identifiers.